# Altering a linked list

Tags: c++

You are given a Single Linked List `a->b->c->d->1->2->3->4->e->f->g->h->5->6->7->8` . You have to alter this list to look like  `a->1->b->2->c->3->d->4->e->5->f->6->g->7->h->8` .

My approach uses an extra list where we remove the numbers form the list and store them separately. Then to merge the lists together. Can someone suggest better techniques to do this?

Comment: Better in which way? Time? Space?

Comment: Better in both, if not then time.

Comment: The given instructions are very vague. What do we want to do? Do we want to consider letters to have the values: a=0.5, b=1.5, c=2.5, d=3.5 etc. and then sort the list while imagining that letters have those values? Or do we want the output list to alternate between letters and numbers, and sort each element type in ascending order indepentently of the other element type? Are letters in the input list guaranteed to be in ascending order if you ignore numbers (and vice versa)? Is it guaranteed that the amount of letters and the amount of numbers in the input list is equal?

Comment: Yes the amount of numbers and the alphabets is equal. And alphabets will occur in ascending order as will numbers but the two of them can be mixed together in any order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would have two iterators.  Have one (iterator A) run through the list, stopping when you hit a number, and have the other (iterator B) stay at the start of the list.  When you hit a number, insert the node at iterator A after the node at iterator B, then move iterator B up.  In this way you don't have to make a separate list.

EDIT: Remove the item at iterator A after you insert it at B (thanks to Tudor for catching).

Comment: You forgot to also remove the number at iterator A. Anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: You can simply swap the pointers instead of inserting and removing.

Comment: How would the swapping of pointers work?
Wouldn't that move b to a wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Take 2 pointers and increment 2nd pointers until you get a number and as soon as you get a number remove the node from here and insert after first pointer.

Since its an interview question, interviewer might be looking at how are you handling all the corner cases like list is null, only two nodes(1-char & 1-int), number of character node and integer node are different in number in a block etc.